# Swift optional types thoughts

Tags: ios, swift, type-safety, optional-arguments

I have a question about: " I guess why it work, but i should ask it here to check my thoughts :D.

I have a code:

```
let possibleNumber = "1232"

var somevariable : Int

if let actualNumber = Int(possibleNumber) {

    somevariable = actualNumber

} else {
    print("\(possibleNumber) could not be converted to an integer")
}

print(somevariable)
```

and mistake: Variable 'somevariable' used before being initialized

But if i had something like this:

```
let possibleNumber = "1232"

var somevariable : Int

if let actualNumber = Int(possibleNumber) {

    somevariable = actualNumber

} else {
    somevariable = 0
}

print(somevariable)
```

It will work without any problems.

If i delete the else block it'l make an error too. In any case, i understand it in that meaning like: i don't allow you to make a situation when *somevariable* can be nil because his type is not optional.

Maybe my thoughts are wrong or you have a better explanation. Thanks for any help and good links.
Good luck!

Comment: Thats why you have optionals in Swift. If you pretend to have a variable which can be nil declare it as optional integer `Int?`

Answer (score 1):

Your thought is right this

```
if let actualNumber = Int(possibleNumber)
```

has a possibility of not being true , and as else doesn't assign a value , hence the error , also you'll get the same error if you only assigned it inside else only , the compiler needs to make sure the value isn't nil because it doesn't know which block ( if or else ) will run at runtime , so depending on your conditions you have to either use `Int!` or `Int?` , but the former will cause a crash if the value is `nil`

Answer (score 1):

The somevariable is used without initialization. So in the first code, there is a possibility to reach the else clause so the somevariable is not initialized.
But in the second case even in the else clause, somevariable is initialized and =0.

These codes work too:

```
let possibleNumber = "1232"
var somevariable : Int?

if let actualNumber = Int(possibleNumber) {

    somevariable = actualNumber

} else {
    print("\(possibleNumber) could not be converted to an integer")
}

print(somevariable)
```

And this:

```
let possibleNumber = "1232"
var somevariable : Int!

if let actualNumber = Int(possibleNumber) {

    somevariable = actualNumber

} else {
    print("\(possibleNumber) could not be converted to an integer")
}

print(somevariable)
```